# Embed a web browser in Windows window using cwebpage

Tags: c, windows, com

I am using cwebpage to embed a browser inside of software.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla

This seems to embed a very old version of IE (which makes sense considering it was originally developed in 2002)

My question is is there anyway to update this easily to use say, Edge? If not, are there updated code bases that does something similar to what this does?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The term "HTML Control" is potentially misleading.  The article you link is about embedding a web browser (specifically IE) in a Windows window as a COM object, using OLE.  An "HTML Control" on the other hand, can easily be interpreted as an `<input>` element in an HTML document.

Comment: Thanks, first post, fixed.

Comment: Edge cannot be embedded the same way as Internet Explorer. Edge embedding is pretty new, covered here (winforms and WPF): https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/ and samples for C++ are available here https://github.com/rjmurillo/webview-samples/tree/master/WinMD/Win32